# Need to Email ALM report from Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, qtp, hp-uft

Test Execution is done from VMs - each VM has UFT and ALM installed. I would like to send ALM report after a test set execution is completed.

The limitation is that there is no outlook available on VM nor access to a shared path. 
Basically the report should be sent at the end of execution without manual intervention.

**Notes/Limitations**:

1. Outlook/Shared drive not available on VM (virtual machine)
2. UFT/ALM is installed on VM
3. Local system has outlook and ALM but not UFT

As naive as it sounds, but is there a way where control is passed back to local machine from VM ?

I would appreciate any ideas/solution or even alternative to achieve this

Comment: You could create a `VBScript` in your local machine that checks ALM to see if all scripts are executed. If they haven't, wait. If they have, send an email from your local machine. If you wanted it more automated, you could use windows scheduler to run the script

Comment: Splendid :). thanks - i shall try it - the only concern i have is if doesn't affect the performance of ALM with load on CPU

Comment: That really depends how you query ALM. Also, you could have a wait of 5 minutes before checking which will reduce the load on CPU

Answer (score 0):

ALM has E-mail sending capabilities if the Server is properly configured. Please note it is the HPE ALM Server that can send out the emails and not the client you use to interact with the Server.

Make sure the server can acccess and SMTP Mail Server [SMTP Mail Server](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.55/online_help/Content/Admin/sa_mail_protocol_setting.htm)

afterwards just configure your test sets under the Automation / Execution tab about emails